# Send data to all clients upon internal event

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js  server that manages list of users. When new user is created, all the clients should display immediately the added user in the list.

I know how to send data to clients without request - using Websocket, but in this implementation, Websocket is not allowed.

Is it possible to update all the client's user-list without using Websocket, when new user is added in the server?

Comment: You can use Long Polling to do this. But, it'll drain your server's juice a lot more than WebSockets do.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Client side
const subscribe = function(callback) {
    var longPoll = function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/messages',
            success: function(data) {
                callback(data)
            },
            complete: function() {
                longPoll()
            },
            timeout: 30000
        })
    }
    longPoll()
}

// Server Side
router.get('/messages', function(req, res) {
    var addMessageListener = function(res) {
        messageBus.once('message', function(data) {
            res.json(data)
        })
    }
    addMessageListener(res)
})
```

Long polling is where the client requests new data from the server, but the server does not respond until there is data. In the meantime, the client has an open connection to the server and is able to accept new data once the server has it ready to send.

Ref: http://hungtran.co/long-polling-and-websockets-on-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

There is a third way: [Push Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)

Your application should register in a Push Notification Server (public or proprietary) and then your server will be able to send messages asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) with an implementation like [`sse-express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-express):

```
// client
let eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:80/updates');

eventSource.addEventListener('connected', (e) => {
    console.log(e.data.welcomeMsg);
    // => Hello world! 
});
```

```
// server
let sseExpress = require('./sse-express');
// ... 
app.get('/updates', sseExpress, function(req, res) {
    res.sse('connected', {
      welcomeMsg: 'Hello world!'
    });
});
```